# Read .txt file c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, readfile

Hy i can't get the content of a .txt file..

```
File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/score.txt")
```

returns "true", but can't access the content with:

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.persistentDataPath + "/score.txt");
```

and neither with:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.persistentDataPath + "/score.txt")) {
   string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
   Debug.Log(line);
}
```

Any solutions for this?

Comment: ...and what is the error? Maybe permissions error?

Comment: There's no error, the lines/line variable is just empty.. and of course there's text in the file :)

Comment: You might want to use `StartUpPath` instead of `persistentDataPath`, and also check whether it returns the path with or without a `\` at the end.

Comment: Also, better use backslash for paths in windows: `@"C:\Windows\bla.txt"`

Comment: I gonna try these things, but i still wonder why File.Exists(//Path) returns true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it, the problem was that

```
Application.persistentDataPath + "/score.txt"
```

Directed me to an empty file which was't actually in my project directory.
So  Application.persistentDataPath directs me into Appdata/ and creates an empty file, but it also creates a file in in the project directory in which the code puts text in.
Still thanks for your help.